# How to merge two tensorflow event files or alternatively tell tensorflow to plot them in the same color?

Tags: tensorboard

I am doing reinforcement learning with a deep neural network with the ray/rllib framework. I am writing out the events of TensorFlow. Sometimes the redis-server failes and the training will stop. After restarting, a new tfevent-file will be created. This results in many different colors in tensorboard.

Is there a way to merge these files or tell TensorBoard to give them the same color in the plot?

Here is an example output of multiple graphs, which shows that for one experiment multiple colors are used by tensorboard.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Tensorboard is able to plot from several event files for the same experiment.

One simple solution here is to place the event files that you want merged in the same directory and watch the curves being merged automatically.